# Count of active members by month...

Tags: mysql

Looking for an elegant solution to this... I find that anything I do is quite ugly... I simply want to plot, for each month, how many users are active (within their start/end dates). Naturally, I need a count of 0 where the month has no active user in that report date range...

```
TABLE MEMBERSHIPS
Name, Start_date, End_date
Joe,  2017/02/01, 2017/04/01
Bob,  2017/03/01, 2017/05/01
Moe,  2017/03/01, 2017/05/01
Lou,  2017/04/01, 2017/05/01
```

So I need a report of active members by month... that is, a count of how many members are active in a given month given a range... So expected results:

```
Reoort for 2017/01/01 to 2017/06/01

Month, Count
 01  |  0
 02  |  1
 03  |  3
 04  |  4
 05  |  3
 06  |  0
```

I am sure this is a common use case... just could not find anything nice...

Thanks,

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: @Strawberry This is what I am leaning to... my current solution uses that... wanted to explore SQL further as it is not my forte...

Comment: In which case, you're current solution is, in my view, the correct approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that a part of the data you need to create the report is missing. How should the database know that you want to include month 01 although there is no data with that month?

An easy way to solve this is creating a table which contains all months the report should include. To simplify things further, instead of the year and the month itself, just write an arbitrary date which lies in the respective month into that table.

```
Table ReportMonths:
ReportMonth datetime
2017-01-15
2017-02-15
2017-03-15
2017-14-15
2017-05-15
2017-06-15
```

To create the report using the new table:

```
SELECT
  ReportMonths.ReportMonth,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  ReportMonths, MEMBERSHIPS
WHERE
  (MEMBERSHIPS.Start_date <= ReportMonths.ReportMonth) AND
  (MEMBERSHIPS.End_date > ReportMonths.ReportMonth)
GROUP BY
  ReportMonths.ReportMonth;
```

**DISCLAIMER**

1) I don't have MySQL at hands right now, so I can't test the code. Please forgive me if there are syntax errors. It should give you a general how to solve your problem, though.

2) If you have millions of rows, that solution might be slow or might make MySQL freak out since it has to build the cross product of the two tables first. If this is the case, we could construct a more sophisticated query which behaves better. Tell us if you are interested ...

**DISCLAIMER END**

The solution above will return the month in question as date. If you don't want that, then `SELECT YEAR(ReportMonths.ReportMonth), MONTH(ReportMonths.ReportMonth), ...` instead of `SELECT ReportMonths.ReportMonth, ...`.

If you don't want to use that second table, then I am afraid you will have to write a stored procedure or a back-end application which loops through every year and month and in every loop selects the count of the rows which start before and end after the current year / month, and then writes that count somewhere, possibly another table or an array, for further processing.

The advantage would be that the database would not have to build the cross product between two tables; the disadvantage would be that this is not a one-query-solution.

Comment: Thanks for this well formulated answer... I was trying to find a more expressive way of doing this. I find that creating this kind of data creates some sort of technical debt... When looking at the code, one wonders what that is and when one looks at the database one wonders what that table is used for... It is not obvious what the code is doing... I hate leaving this in my code...

Comment: Then you could perhaps make the second table a temporary table. That way, it won't hang around in the database forever. Alternatively, you could write a stored procedure or a back-end application which works like described in the last part of my answer. Finally, I admit that I might not have chosen the best name for the new table or its column; you might get an acceptable result if you assign meaningful names. You could also use two columns for month and year in the new table and change the code accordingly. That way, it should get pretty clear what the new table is used for.

Comment: Went ahead and accepted the answer even if I ended up doing it in application code... Thank you for your time and well thought out answer...

Comment: Thank you very much. I probably would have done it the same way.